# is there a default http verb match method for rails routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I was looking up some code examples for a new method I'm learning to use on GitHub and came across someones routes file that looks like this.

```
match '/arbitrary_name', to: 'controller#action'
match '/arbitrary_name2', to: 'controller#action2'
```

I've definitely read that you should always state a http ver with match but somehow this worked. could someone explain this for me?

Comment: check your `rake routes`, you'll have the answer there :)

Comment: "you should always state a http verb with match" - nope.

Comment: the verb is the HTTP method. Get is the default method accessed when you type an address in the address bar. Other methods are javascript enabled. It's recommended to add a method as explained here http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Base.html#method-i-match because it helps the controller know what action it should pick ('patch' trigger update action, 'Post' trigger create action etc) Also all methods but GET cannot easily be simulated by a hacker. I am not sure but a match without a method should default to 'Get' method